# Laravel pagination get next page

Tags: laravel, pagination

I have a an api which will fetch data that is paginated by 10 items. Here's my logic:

```
public function getGamesResult(Request $request)
{
    // Validations
    $rules = [
        'from'=>'required|string',
        'to'=> 'required|string'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {

        // Validation failed
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $validator->messages(),
        ]);
    }

    $params =  $request->all();

    $games = Game::whereBetween("game_date", [$params["from"], $params["to"]])->paginate(10);
    $result = [];

    foreach ($games as $game) {

        $win_data = [];
        $winners = $game->result()->get();

        // Get Winning Number Records
        foreach ($winners as $win)
        {
            $winning_numbers_arr = explode(',', $win->winning_numbers);


            $win_data[] = [
                'game_id' => $win->game_id,
                'created_dt' => $win->created_dt
            ];

        }

        $result[] = [
            'game_data' => [
            'game_id' => $game->id,
            'game_date' => $game->game_date
        ],
            'winning_number' => $win_data
        ];
    }

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'data' => $result,
        'total'=> $games->total(),
        'count'=> $games->count(),
        'hasMorePages'=> $games->hasMorePages(),
        'currentPage'=> $games->currentPage()
    ]);
}
```

My question is how do laravel knows when I want to fetch the next 10 records? Or am I doing it wrong? If there are total of 3000 records, how will I get the next page using this same logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel's paginator contains the all the logic to get the next page automatically of the request

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results

If you add `?page=2` at the end of your url it will fetch the second page. If no argument is passed it assumes page 1.

Comment: Thanks! I able to test it by just adding page parameter.